# How to Set Focus in Access Continuous Form (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

Right now it's being ignored. Here's the code at it's most basic, it causes an inescapable scenario currently, but I plan to condition these out. Just need to get the basic setFocus working.

```
Private Sub fieldbox_LostFocus() 
Me.fieldbox.SetFocus
End Sub
```

In a regular form, it works as expected. When fieldbox loses focus, the focus is set back onto fieldbox.

In a continuous form, it does not work, and the set focus does not happen. This is possibly due to multiple instances of fieldbox existing for each record.

What I'd like is if fieldbox1, 2 and 3 exist on the continuous form, and you click out of fieldbox2, how do I set focus back to fieldbox2?

Comment: Why do you want to? Personally, I think it sounds like a flawed design if you need to _force_ the user's focus to a specific area. Can you give more background as to why you need this functionailty?

Comment: You will have to specify the record as well as the control (fieldbox).  I agree with the comment that more info will prolly help us.

Comment: If you enter bad data, force the user back to the fieldbox for correction before any other events occur.

Comment: @smandoli, do you have any code examples for specifying the record and control? are they currentRecord and gotoRecord?

Comment: Having learned that data-validation is the goal, my advice to specify-the-record isn't applicable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the form's `BeforeUpdate()` event instead of focus:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel as Integer)
If RecordOK = False Then
  Dim response, strMsg as String
  strMsg = "There is data missing from the record.  " _
    & vbCrLf & "Press Yes to continue, editing.  " _
    & vbCrLf & "Press No to discard all changes."
  Cancel = True
  response = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo)
  If response <> vbYes
    Me.Undo
  End If
End If
```

Code above is not tested, may need some tweaks, paste and see.  My recent update provides cleaner handling of the user's response to the dialog box.  (You do have `Option Explicit` set, don't you?!)

A good explanation of this method at the **control** level is found [here](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/access_event_programming/beforeupdate.htm).  But you may want to use the **form** event, as above.  Sometimes I just temporarily insert `Msgbox` cues in the events so I can see what is firing when.

Note the dialog box should provide clues on how to avoid wiping the work done so far by a user.

Comment: He might be able to do similar with `Me.fieldbox`'s Before Update.

Comment: yea I was afraid you lead into beforeUpdate with a me.undo ultimatum. What I was trying to set up was a complete workaround to beforeUpdate cancle = true not working, and me.undo completely wiping out changes made. I hate this approach because a number of things can occur before beforeUpdate happens. In which case if the field in question was wrong, it wipes out all changes that could have happened afterwards. Hence why I'm trying to put the attention immediately to the bad entry.

Comment: @HansUp trying beforeUpdate for the fieldbox produces error 2108. you must save the field before you execute ... the setfocus method.

Comment: @thomas Perhaps I overlooked some details because I'm unsure whether I'm on the same page as you.  But I can tell you that when you set `Cancel = True` in `Me.fieldbox`'s Before Update event procedure, the focus remains on `Me.fieldbox` ... so `SetFocus` not needed there.

Comment: Thank you @HansUp.  My sample code needs your insights.

Comment: @Smandoli I still don't understand exactly what thomas wants.  ;-)

Comment: @hansup I just tried cancle = true without setfocus on the fieldbox. it doesn't work, I can click out of it no problem. In my experience, cancel=true has not worked for me with anything. If it did, I wouldn't have to be jumping hoops for this and I'd just use the form's beforeUpdate to control everything. But as it stands, it doesn't work for me. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Smandoli  I want Access' front end to prevent users from entering bad data. Of course users can enter bad data a long with other fields/subforms. A number of edits (without save) can occur, before user decides to hit save. I'd love form beforeUpdate to check against everything, but since cancel = true still proceeds to update/afterUpdate, it doesn't do me any good. And the only answer I've gotten was me.undo, which wipes out all user's recent edits. If cancel = true for the form's beforeUpdate worked, I wouldn't need to be doing this.

Comment: I empathize because I've been in the same kind of spot: form-automation can be very frustrating.  I'm sure this general approach is what you need.  You have to try and test until you get to the desired result.

Comment: Access is just clunky, I've tested so many options as work around. A lot of times I just let the regular error go up as it handles exactly what I'd want it to do. It's just ugly for users and when they see it they panic so much.

Comment: You say the regular error "handles exactly what you'd want it to do".  But in this case, it still leaves the control focus problem, does it not?